# Can not run test suite from command line using "mvn test" from root directory

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm relatively new to Java/Maven and trying to run a Maven project TestNG suite from command line. It builds but does not run the tests. They work ok from Eclipse.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------< com.agricorp:AutomationResourcesFramework >--------------
[INFO] Building FBRAutomationTestSuite 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ AutomationResourcesFramework ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\TFS\TS JAVA Automation\Development\FBRAutomationTestSuite\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ AutomationResourcesFramework ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:testResources (default-testResources) @ AutomationResourcesFramework ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\TFS\TS JAVA Automation\Development\FBRAutomationTestSuite\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ AutomationResourcesFramework ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 23 source files to C:\TFS\TS JAVA Automation\Development\FBRAutomationTestSuite\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ AutomationResourcesFramework ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\TFS\TS JAVA Automation\Development\FBRAutomationTestSuite\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@47d384ee
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.611 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.055 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-25T18:00:46-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've added the project setup below. Renamed `testng.xml` to `FBRAutomationTestSuite.xml`.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Added the complete `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.agricorp</groupId>
  <artifactId>FBRAutomationTestSuite</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>FBRAutomationTestSuite</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <!--framework.jar.path>C:/Users/nram/.m2/repository/com/agricorp/AutomationResourcesFramework/1.0</framework.jar.path-->
    <framework.jar.path>C:\TFS\TS JAVA Automation\Development</framework.jar.path>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency> 
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.0</version>
        <!--scope>test</scope-->
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8</version>
    </dependency>           
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codoid.products/fillo -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codoid.products</groupId>
        <artifactId>fillo</artifactId>
        <version>1.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.agricorp</groupId>
        <artifactId>AutomationResourcesFrameworks</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${framework.jar.path}/AutomationResourcesFramework.jar</systemPath>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>SanityTests</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>RegressionTests</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>FBRAutomationTestSuite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml?

Comment: Note that Java convention says that package names should be all-lowercase. Also, run `mvn -X test` (you'll get very detailed output) and see what Maven is looking for as an entry point; I'm not that familiar with TestNG, but I know that for JUnit by default it looks for classes whose names end in `Test`.

Comment: It may be personal taste but I wouldn't use a framework in Maven that has only an `ant` example on its [Welcome page](https://testng.org/doc/index.html) which als contains two 404 links to a blog that should explain the reasons for creating TestNG, and that refers to JUnit 4 on its Migration page now that JUnit 5 is out for 5 years.

Comment: cont'd: ... and of which the [Maven Surefire page](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html) mentions "_Unsupported TestNG versions - TestNG 5.14.3: Bad formatted pom.xml. - TestNG 5.14.4 and 5.14.5: TestNG is using a missing dependency (org.testng:guice:2.0). Excluding it, may break some features._"

Comment: Added the complete pom.xml file above.

Comment: @Gerold Broser - Where did you see the error messages above? I can not find them. TestNG version is 7.4.0.

Comment: @user10829672 There are 2 dead links on the Welcome page at "_on my weblog here and here_". The text on the  Maven Surefire page are notes, not errors.

Comment: I mean this error where did you find it? in pom.xml or some other file?  "Unsupported TestNG versions - TestNG 5.14.3: Bad formatted pom.xml. - TestNG 5.14.4 and 5.14.5: TestNG is using a missing dependency (org.testng:guice:2.0). Excluding it, may break some features."

Comment: Also Im unable find the Welcome Page. Where is it or in which file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236453/discussion-between-user10829672-and-gerold-broser).

Comment: @user10829672 Follow the two links in my two comments above.

Comment: Why do you use `<artifactId>AutomationResourcesFrameworks ... <scope>system`? `AutomationResourcesFrameworks.jar` is in your local Maven repo so there's no need for explicit path and  `<scope>` declarations. Just t a normal `<dependency>` declaration is sufficient. And, BTW, `<artifactId>` naming convention is `automation-resources-frameworks`. Have you read [Maven / POM Reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html) completely already?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using profiles here.
Tests with specific profile can be run using command:

```
mvn test -Pprofilename
```

So for your case it will be :

```
mvn test -PRegressionTests
```